# Open-In for any PDF viewed on UIWebview

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

Alright I've been searching and testing for the last few weeks, I am new to this xcode stuff, but I know enough to get the application up and running. So the problem I have been having is adding this open-in feature. I can get it to work with local pdfs (pdfs I manually and locally load on the app) but I can't seem to get it to work for the PDF's that I am currently viewing on the app. Lets say I bring up a PDF, one of which I dont have loaded on the app nor do I even know what the URL is, a random one, I can't seem to figure out how to get the open-in action button to work. Heres my code. oh and btw I am trying to open-in to Adobe Reader, and again I can successfully do it with a local pdf, i have the app installed and everything. Please Help!

1.) Note: I know this loads the PDF Locally which works:

```
- (IBAction)shareButton:(id)sender;{

    NSString * currentURL = _webview.request.URL.absoluteString;
    NSString * filename = [currentURL stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSLog(filename);
    NSString * filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"OOP_ObjC" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSLog(filePath);
    docController =[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:currentURL]];
    docController.delegate = self;
    docController.UTI = @"com.adobe.pdf";
    [docController presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:_shareButton animated:YES];

    [super viewDidLoad] 
}
```

---

2.) Note: And this is what Ive been trying to use to download the PDF and Load it locally. but i keep getting `-[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:];` nil string parameter'

```
- (IBAction)shareButton:(id)sender;{

     NSString * currentURL = _webview.request.URL.absoluteString;
     NSString * filename = [currentURL stringByDeletingPathExtension];
     NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filename]];


     //Store the Data locally as PDF File

     NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
     NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mypdf.pdf"];
    [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    //Now create Request for the file that was saved in your documents folder

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [webView setDelegate:self];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

    NSLog(filePath);
    NSString * path =
    [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:filePath ofType:@"pdf"];
    docController =[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
    docController.delegate = self;
    docController.UTI = @"com.adobe.pdf";
    [docController presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:_shareButton animated:YES];

    [super viewDidLoad] 
}
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 NSString * path =
    [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:filePath ofType:@"pdf"];
```

in second method (webView one) you are searching for file in the app's bundle.. however you have it saved in app's document folder..not app bundle. remove that line

and change this one

```
docController =[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
```

**to**

```
docController =[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: url]; // url is of the file that you saved by downloading.
```

Comment: that worked, but when i press the button it is not saving the correct pdf, I have an index pdf that has multiple links to separate pdfs, after selecting one and then pressing the button it brings me back to the index pdf and then presents the button to open in adobe which works, I just want to be able to save the PDF I had on screen when i pressed the button, any ideas? Thanks for your help by the way, much appreciated.

Comment: I got it to work finally, please thumbs this up so everyone can see how to get this to work

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer with the help of Shaggy of course, please thumbs this up so everyone can see how to get this to work, (because it literally took me months!) im adding all the code.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NinthViewController : UIViewController  <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
    UIDocumentInteractionController *docController;
}
- (IBAction)shareButton:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityind;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIDocumentInteractionController *docController;
@end
```

---

```
#import "NinthViewController.h"

@interface NinthViewController ()
@end
@implementation NinthViewController
@synthesize docController;


-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)X didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Can't connect. Please check your internet connection and try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:@"Try again", nil];
    [alert show];

}

//Implement the 'Try again' button action
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR MAIN  URL SITE"];
        NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
        [webView loadRequest:req];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *website = @"YOUR MAIN URL SITE";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:website];
    NSURLRequest *requestUrl = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    (webView.scalesPageToFit = YES);
    [webView loadRequest:requestUrl];
    [webView addSubview:_activityind];
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(loading) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (IBAction)shareButton:(id)sender
{
    NSString * currentURL = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
    NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentURL]];
    NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
    NSString* theFileName = [[currentURL lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[theFileName stringByAppendingString:@".pdf"]];
    [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    docController =[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
    docController.delegate = self;
    [docController presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)loading {

    if (!webView.loading)
        [_activityind stopAnimating];
    else
        [_activityind startAnimating]; 
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```